# How to read contacts of phone in Android using AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I am trying to read the contacts from the phone using Async Task with Async it works perfectly without Async Task, but this takes too much time when I try without Async. So I want to try this with Async.

Comment: `AsyncTask` is deprecated. Please consider other threading solutions, perhaps tied into some form of reactive framework (`LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks solved its with executer service.